# Is it possible to programmatically upgrade/downgrade to a specific version of a running ClickOnce app?

Tags: .net, clickonce

I know that I can programmatically upgrade to the latest version of the running ClickOnce application, but can I go to a specific version that may not be the latest version?

Here is the use case:  The application detects that the current user is configured as a beta tester and so he should be on version v.BETA, but everyone else running the app should be on version v.STABLE.

It doesn't seem like what I'm trying to do is possible but perhaps there is a better way to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of goes against the idea of ClickOnce.

If you want to have beta testers test a new version of your app, I'd recommend deploying a new ClickOnce application to a different location and restrict access to that location within your site.

This way, all of your users will be using the production version and the beta testers can get to your new version when they are ready to start testing.

I think doing something the way you are thinking of will cause more harm than good.